# Question on vectors addition in case of regular hexagon .

Tags: vectors

There is a regular hexagon given to you ABCDEF.It is asked to find the sum of AB + AC+AD+AE+AF vectors.

I am not getting is how will we make the directions of vectors or you can say head and tail of the hexagon vectors.

Done till now :

1 I have AF vectors as the resultant using polygon law.

2Then taken vectors AC,AD,AE and AF(This one is already made as well).

$ What I saw done online and doubts I got.

Q They took OC vector direction to make AC = AO+OC.OC direction is not given then how can they say that.Maybe it is CO as well.[image]

If my doubt for OC vector is cleared.I think I can solve it.

Please do share if you have some other method to solve it.

Please help.

Comment: It is a regular hexagon so $OC = AB$ and $OC \parallel AB$. $\triangle ABO$ and $\triangle OCB$ are equilateral triangles.

Comment: OMG.Do you mean to say since AB IS // OC .Then OC has same direction has AB

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: Can’t they be parallel even if direction is not same.That is too correct right.

Comment: The direction is either same or opposite directions. It cannot be anything else.

Comment: So if they are opposite.Then AC will not be equal to AO and OC right ?

Comment: We don’t know actually the direction.

Comment: $\vec{AC} = \vec{AO} + \vec{OC}$ is clear.

Comment: My suggestion, first think in terms of geometry. Do you understand why $AB$ and $OC$ are parallel?

Comment: 1 They will never meet each other.2 since it is a regular hexagon,AB =OC.Angle AOB = Angle ABC

Comment: $\angle ABO = \angle BOC$. So $AB$ and $OC$ are parallel. But even if they were not parallel, the vector addition does not change. $\vec{AC} = \vec{AO} + \vec{OC}$ will still be true.

Comment: @user277768 A suggestion, please attempt to draw on MS paint, or any computer based application instead of a photograph. Computer Vision is increasing in accuracy and a neat photo may make your question as a valuable resource.

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi ok I will

Comment: @MathLover I think I have got you.

Comment: OC DIRECTION WILL BE TOWARDS AB BECAUSE IT HAS TO BE.SINCE WE ALREADY MADE AN AC VECTOR

Comment: I HAVE UNDERSTOOD THAT THEY WERE EQUAL BUT WAS A BIT CONFUSED WITH DIRECTIONS.I THINK I HAVE GOT IT NOW.THANK YOU @MathLover

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Note $AD=2AO$.

$AOCB$ is a parallelogram. So $AC=AO+AB$

$AOEF$ is a parallelogram. $AE=AO+AF$

$ABOF$ is also a parallelogram. So $AB+AF=AO$

Summing, $$AB+AC+AD+AE+AF=4AO+2(AB+AF)=6AO$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that since we have a regular hexagon,

$$\begin{align}
AB + AC + AD + AE + AF &= (AB + AF) + (AC + AE) + AD \\
\\
&= (AB + BO) + [(AB + BC) + (AF + FE)] + AD \\
\\
&= AO + [(AB + BC + AF) + FE] + AD \\
\\
&= AO + [(AB + BC + CD) + AO] + AD \\
\\
&= AO + [AD + AO] + AD \\
\\
&= AO + 2AO + AO + 2AO \\
\\
&= 6AO
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

If $O$ is the centre of the regular hexagon

$$\begin{aligned}
AB + \dots +AF&= 5AO + OB +\dots +OF\\
&=5AO-OA+OA+ OB+\dots +OF\\
&=6AO
\end{aligned}$$

As the sum
$$OA+\dots +OF$$ vanishes.

Comment: How did you get 5 AO and OB+...OF sir?

Comment: For any points $M,N$, you have $MN =MO+ON$. Apply that 5 times to $AB, AC...$.

Comment: I am just thinking on it.

Comment: And I made a mistake that is now corrected.

Comment: That is exactly my doubt

Comment: YOUR SECOND COMMENT.

Comment: Since we are dealing with vectors.Can’t OC have different direction

Comment: Then they may not be equal .

Comment: I made no assumption on the directions of the vectors, except that for a regular hexagon $OA+ \dots +OF=0$.

Comment: Shouldn’t we make direction assumption because they are given in vector form and have directions.

Comment: Please read again my answer line by line and raise a specific doubt on one of the precise equality if you have one. All what I wrote is about vectors.

Comment: Ok.I will Thank you for helping though.

Comment: I have understood now.